# Adding properties to many to many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have been using Core Data to model my database. I have 2 entities that are in many to many relationship. Each person can have many addresses, and on each address multiple persons can live.

Now i would like to add property to this relationship. For example one person - address will have label home, other person - address can will have label mama's place.

I can't add this property on address entity, because same address will have different labels for different persons.

Since relationships are modeled like `NSSet`s, I don't see a way to do what I want.

Can this be somehow done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add attributes to a many-many relationship directly.  The Apple-recommended approach (see ["Modelling a relationship based on its semantics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) in the CoreData Programming Guide) is to replace the many-many relationship with an intermediate entity, to which you add the attributes.  Each of your existing entities will have a one-many relationship with the new entity.

In your case, you might have something like this:

```
Person     <--->> PersonAddressDetails <<--->    Address
```

You can then add the `label` attribute to the `PersonAddressDetails` entity.

Comment: is there a simple way to extract the PersonAddressDetails for a given Address and Person combination or would you have to extract the set from one and iterate over it to get the one belonging to the other as well?

Comment: @alionthego I guess you could use the Swift intersection method on the two sets, to get the PersonAddressDetails object that is common to both the Person and the Address.  Or you could fetch with a suitable predicate specifying the relevant Person and Address.  But I tend to filter one set with a predicate specifying the other object.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  swift intersection would be perfect but it only works on sets, not nssets which is what the relation objects are saved to.  I suppose I could cast that to a set but not sure if that will work.  As for the filter technique, I'm assuming you create a mutable copy of the nsset first?  as someone who doesn't work with sets often, would that create a copy of the core data objects in the set?  I definitely don't want that.  I want any change to the filtered objects to be reflected to the original object.  thanks.