# coreData many to many relation adding additional properties to relation table

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation in my coreData model for blogs and forums.  Each forum can have multiple blogs and each blog can belong to multiple forums.

I would like to set a unique bool property for the blog having been seen but this property will vary in each forum.

Is it possible to have a property in a many to many relation that can be set for a blog/forum combination?  i.e. blogSeen bool variable that is unique for every blog/forum relation.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227350/3985749) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for cannot be achieved with only using the two entities in your Core Data model. One solution is to add an additional entity that maps another relation between the `Blog` and `Forum` for tracking when an item is read/viewed.

For instance, consider the following:

[image]

In this model, a `Viewed` entity was added. The `Viewed` entity has a to-one relationship to a `Blog` and a `Forum`. the `Blog`/`Forum` entities has an inverse to-many relationship to a `Viewed` object.

Each time a `Blog` has been seen/viewed/read for a particular `Forum` a `Viewed` entity should be created. The `Blog`/`Forum` pairing in the `Viewed` entities should be unique. This will allow you to track the read/unread states of the blogs for each forum.

Here's a simple extension on `Forum` for that purpose.

```swift
extension Forum {
    public var readBlogs: [Blog] {
        guard let viewed = self.inverseViewed as? Set<Viewed> else {
            return []
        }

        var blogs = [Blog]()

        viewed.forEach { (viewed) in
            if let blog = viewed.blog {
                blogs.append(blog)
            }
        }

        return blogs
    }

    public var unreadBlogs: [Blog] {
        guard let allBlogs = self.blogs as? Set<Blog> else {
            return []
        }

        var unreadBlogs = Array(allBlogs)
        self.readBlogs.forEach { (blog) in
            if let index = unreadBlogs.index(of: blog) {
                unreadBlogs.remove(at: index)
            }
        }

        return unreadBlogs
    }
}
```